# Overused server, what files to delete to create diskspace

Tags: windows-server-2003, disk-space-utilization

Being cheap, I am after ideas to help clean up my 8G C: drive on a Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition. With just under 1G free, I need to free up more space to install service packs.

I have questions regarding candidate files to delete. Are the following safe to get rid of:

c:\WINDOWS\kb*.log - I am guessing service pack log files, any danger in deleting these

c:\WINDOWS\system32\c_*.nls - duno what these are

C:\Documents and Settings has old user account folder setup that are not being used. Can I just delete these directly from win explorer

What are other good candidates?

Currently treeview says:

4,238MB WINDOWS

2,950MB Program Files

595M Documents and Settings

I don't want to buy more space just yet.

Answer (score 2):

Old user accounts - use the user profiles from the system properties to delete them so you wipe any cruft from the registry as well.

Log files *shouldn't* be an issue to delete as long as they're not open.

Compression can help. Slows a little, especially if short on RAM, but can help.

Turn on "show hidden files" and in the Windows (or windows system) folder there should be a huge bunch of hidden compressed files used to roll back changes to updates. I usually don't have a problem "deleting" them as long as I have a backup in place and don't think I'll be rolling back any system updates in the future.

Suggestion - get your hands on an external hard disk and instead of deleting things, move them to the other storage. If there's an issue where the server goes kaplooey in the next day or two, you can restore it rather easily. Just don't use FAT on the external storage as large files can have issues with it.

I usually use 7zip to compress things I'm not sure that I'll need for awhile and archive it. Free, fast, can create self-extracting executables and tends to be better than ZIP.

Double check your windows components have just what you need installed. No need to have games if you don't use them (on a server??)

Double check that your program files subdir has just the programs you currently run in there. I have deleted old subdir cruft that was left behind from uninstalls.

Check that there aren't multiple versions of Java installed if you don't need them.

Check for caching of crud. Temp internet files, temp folders used for downloads, and cache directories in user subdirs are candidates for checking. I use "bytecount" (freeware) to get a good estimate on sizes of subdirectories because it's uber-tiny and simple to use.

Comment: Mighty suggestions! I have an external disk being used to the max. Just would like to keep the C: one very lean. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Windows tends to hide tons of non-essential data in the c drive. Here are a few common problems:

- Huge event logs (Application, System,
  Security)
- IIS Logs (they can compress at almost
  95%)
- C:\WINDOWS\PCHealth has a bunch of
  windows crash reports
- NTBackup logs... these annoying
  catalogs chew up space with no
  purpose (you can always directly
  catalog the tape or backup file later
  manually) C:\Documents and
  Settings\All Users\Application
  Data\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\NTBackup\catalogs51

Check out WinDirStat (http://windirstat.info/) Rather than guessing where the space is taken up, you'll be able to visually see a graphic representation of files and folders helping you to pinpoint problem areas.

As a LAST resort, you can remove all those $NTUNINSTALL files in c:\windows
http://www3.telus.net/dandemar/spack.htm

Comment: As a general rule I delete any $NTUNINSTALL that is more than a few months old. No need leaving unintsallers for a patch that was put on the server years ago and less need for ones that are 6 months old.

Comment: Of a patch was put and is still there how would you know it is relevant. Cheers for the link - it describes how to take these off but I am still weary as they dont show up in Ctrl Panel > Add/Remove programs .

Comment: When you go to Add/Remove Programs there is a check box at the top labeled "Show updates". If you check that box all the updates that are related to the $NTUNINSTALL files will be shown in Add/Remove Programs. Each will have a Click here for support information link that will take you to the Microsoft knowledgebase and describe the purpose of the patch. Note that all updates will show in this list even after you delete the $NTUNINSTALL files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched on compression?

Comment: File compression, disk compression explain..

Comment: Start, Computer, select C: drive, right click and choose Properties, select compress drive option - it goes off and compresses as much as it can. Can save OCEANS of disk space.

Comment: Is this really safe on a server? See http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/271438.htm. Although SQL databases are on another drive, I am still weary it may relate to more problems. ta!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about 'service pack log files' but log files in general are a good candidate for deletion. Especially if you're not using the information in them.

Incidentally, nls suggests 'national language support', but the few links I found when I googled it were about difficulty *reading* them, so I don't know if they're a cause of your problems.